# sql to filter search on multiple drop down lists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 drop down lists refer to as ddl1 and ddl2,
when I select ddl1 it populates entire results for that search.
When I select ddl2 to refine the search no changes are made.

How do I achieve a refined search from the below sql queries

```
<?php

$q=$_GET["q"];
$p=$_GET["p"];

require 'connection.php';

mysqli_select_db($con,"Faults" );

//where statement in the sql syntax will select where in db to get infor, use AND to add another condition
$sql="SELECT Products.Product_Name, Versions.Version, Platform.Platform_Name, Issues.Issue, Issues.Sub_Issue, Issues.Fix
      FROM Solutions 
         INNER JOIN Products 
             ON Solutions.Product = Products.Product_id
         INNER JOIN Versions 
             ON Solutions.Product_Version = Versions.Version_id
         INNER JOIN Platform 
             ON Solutions.Product_Platform = Platform.Platform_id
         INNER JOIN Issues 
             ON Solutions.Product_Issue = Issues.Issue_id
      WHERE Product = '".$q."' 
      OR (Product_Issue = '".$p."' 
      OR Product_Issue ='".$p."')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//below is the echo statment to create the results in a table format, list collumn titles

echo "<table id=tables border='1'> 
          <tr>
              <th>Products</th>
              <th>Version</th>
              <th>Platform</th>
              <th>Issue</th>
              <th>Sub Issue</th>
              <th>Fix</th>
          </tr>";

//below is script to list reults in a table format, $row [row name on table] 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Product_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Version'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Platform_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Issue'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Sub_Issue'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"idfix.php?Fix=" . nl2br($row['Fix']) . "\">Fix</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

// below closes the coonection to mysql

?>
```

JS code

```
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+ product.value +"&" +"p="+ issue.value ,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `sql-server` when you're actually using `mysqli_*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming $q is the value for dropdown list 1 and $p is the value for dropdown list 2.

One way to achieve what you want is to default $p to a `LIKE` wildcard when no value is selected in ddl2, and then just bring in the ddl2 value if something is selected.

The last part of you query could then just be:

```
WHERE Product = '".$q."' 
AND Product_Issue LIKE '".$p."'
```

So if no ddl2 value is selected, you get a `LIKE '%'`, which will basically not filter, and if something is selected you'll get a `LIKE 'value'`, which is generally equivalent to the `= 'value'` you're currently going for (there are some differences, but usually none that affect general queries like this). Using `LIKE` should also allow any table indexes you have set up to continue working as well.

To see any impact of `LIKE` vs `=`, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

You could also just add in the ddl2 part of the query dynamically (append to your query string) based on selection of a ddl2 value.

Comment: this doesnt wrk fully dd1 updates correct but when dd2 is selected no change but if selected first will work correctly. I have edited in my js code to see if this helps

Comment: like statement was correct path to go down, i just need to make value for ddl in the html have a starting value of "" this then allowed the code to work. so marking your answer as answer to my question as it lead me to the answer